# Xcode Target Name blank - cannot change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Somehow my target name got wiped out.  Now I cannot change it.  Has this happened to anyone?

[image]

I can not click on the area to enter text like normal.. I am completely locked out from changing it.

help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your project settings and open the small ">" character that appears up near the top left of that window, a list of targets will slide out.

And when you select a target from that list, you can change the name of the Target via the "Identity and Type" inspector in the right pane.

Like this:

[image: Change Target Name Here]

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thank you for the reply.  My identity and type inspector shows nothing though. it is very weird.  Clicking on my blank Target does not bring up any options in the inspector.

Answer (score -1):

Just select xcodeproject on left side bar press enter change the name [image]

After enter your new name

This Dialog box is appear [image]

click on rename

Comment: This changes a bunch of file names and not just the target name.