# What is the xcode Target name?

Tags: xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

what belongs in the application target name in this podfile. I pulled this from the google getting started site for ios google maps sdk. Where can I find that in Xcode?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode and Select the folder icon on left(i.e Project navigator) select the blue icon file and on the right you can see the target under TARGETS heading.

Refer this for more detail: [Xcode Target Name blank - cannot change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842749/xcode-target-name-blank-cannot-change)